# double the number in the mips

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

The task is:
"Modify the program shown in Figure 3-4. Ask the user to enter an integer value, then print the result of doubling that number. Use the add statement.", and this is the program I need to modify:

```
        .data
str1: .asciiz "Prosze podac liczb: \n"
str2: .asciiz "Wprowadzona liczba to:"
    
    .text
main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str1
    syscall
    li $v0, 5
    syscall 
    move $s0, $v0
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str2
    syscall
    li $v0, 1 
    move $a0, $s0
    syscall 
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: You need to describe what you've tried and where you're stuck. FYI, We offer enlightenment, but don't do your homework for you.  FYI, 2x = x+x.

Comment: MARS has a single step debugging feature, maybe you can use that to find your numbers.

Comment: I don't want anyone to do anything for me. As you can see, I solved the task to some extent, which suggests the presence of code, which for a beginner who is familiar with a new technology, in this case with assembly, I still consider it a good result. If I wanted this task solved for me, I would write it like this. And I'm just wondering what this doubling is all about. I read that an add statement is needed

Comment: Yes, 2x = x + x, so mathematically we know we can double by adding.  We can triple by the following equalities: 3x = x + x + x and also 3x = 2x + x